# File system class structure in scala

Tags: scala

What would be the appropriate way to implement a file system class structure in scala?

I want the `Root` to be a `Directory` and to have itself as a parent.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

sealed trait Entry
class Directory(val parent: Directory, val content: mutable.IndexedSeq[Entry]) extends Entry
class File(val parent: Directory, val content: String) extends Entry
object Root extends Directory(Root, mutable.IndexedSeq[Entry]())
```

The attempt above results in:

Error:

> (23, 31) super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless
>   parameter is declared by-name object Root extends Directory(Root, IndexedSeq())

Comment: It would be empty in the beginning, but you could add entries to `Root.content`.

Comment: I updated my question to use mutable collections.

Comment: Can you say what is your goal? Why do you need bi-directional references?

Comment: I would like e.g. to list all entries of a directory but would also like to print a parent directory of a file/directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is create a 2nd trait just for directories.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer  // easier to update

sealed trait Entry
sealed trait Directory extends Entry {
  val parent  :Directory
  val content :ArrayBuffer[Entry]
}

class File(val parent  :Directory
          ,val content :String) extends Entry

class SubDir(val parent  :Directory
            ,val content :ArrayBuffer[Entry]) extends Directory

object Root extends Directory {
  override val parent  :Directory = this
  override val content :ArrayBuffer[Entry] = ArrayBuffer()
}
```

Now you can create/update directory contents, and the parent of `Root` is still `Root`.

```
Root.content += new File(Root, "name")
Root.content += new SubDir(Root, ArrayBuffer())

Root.parent.parent.parent  //res2: Directory = Root$@294c7935
```

Comment: Seems reasonable. Thanks.